# How to access the returned object of JQuery "POST" method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-post

I have a JQuery "POST" method which returns value

Objects:    `[{"in_approved":0, "out_approved":0},{"in_approved":1, "out_approved":2}]`

Ajax method:

```
$.ajax({
        data: {
                "start_date" : startDate,
                "end_date" : endDate
        },
        url: "/admin/analytics",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response)
        {

            // Accessing returned object

        },
        error : function(request, status, thrownError){
            alert("Error");
            return;
                }
    });
```

Now, to access the returned object I am using

```
$.each(response.data, function(index,row){
   var in_approved = row.in_approved; 
  alert(in_approved); // just to see if the value is being stored in the variable.
});
```

But when I do this I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Can anyone explain to me what this error means?

Also how to access the values of the returned object?

Answer (score 1):

`response` will be the array that you posted. It does not have a `data` property, so it will inevitably not be found  when you look for it! Just loop through the array:

```
$.each(response, function(index,row){
```

Answer (score 1):

The `response` is an array of Objects.. So you need to iterate over it as an array.

```
$.each(response, function(index,row){
```

But you are trying to iterate over **response.data**

your `$.each` will work on this object

```
data : [{"in_approved":0, "out_approved":0},{"in_approved":1, "out_approved":2}]
```